# How to proceed Hunza/Swat/Naran/Skardu with valid Karachi Visa for an Indian National?

Tags: indian-citizens, tourist-visas, pakistan

For an Indian national who already has a Karachi Visa; is it mandatory to get a 
 NOC to visit beautiful places like Hunza Tour(Gilgit-Baltistan), Skardu Tour, Swat Tour or similar places in the northern areas of Pakistan.

Latest news from Pakistan Foreign Ministry says that various parts of the country that were earlier out of bounds to foreigners and required No-Objection Certificates (NOC) to visit are now open to them. Does it mean that it applies to only 171 countries excluding India and Israel? Under such circumstances where half of my relatives hail from Northern areas(Dheer, Abbottabad); how could my wish come true?

For a moment, if I consider visiting the Ministry of Interior, Islamabad then I would be violating the visa rule and asking a government official directly to provide NoC.

Kindly advise under such circumstances; how could I proceed? I truly admire the beauty of the Northern Areas in Pakistan.

Comment: Hi, Ata. Whether you should visit Pakistan or Switzerland is very much a matter of personal preference, so I've deleted that part of your question. With information about what you would need to do to visit Pakistan, you should be able to make that decision on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your update, David. Well, making a decision depends on current circumstances considering the arch-rival countries. Any decision I make, it should not lead to any consequences that hamper the entire vacation. Hence posted such question to get to know the feedback if anyone had come across such situation. Thanks in advance.